# Laravel - Notify or dispatch job queue worker laravel can cause double select with lock table?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, cron, queue

Can two Laravel workers can use the same Transaction DB?

I have Job Process A which will call/dispatch Job Process B if there is data in table A with flag `is_processed` = 0. What it does is:

```sql
-- first select data with lock
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE is_proccesed = 0
LIMIT 1000
FOR UPDATE OF tableA SKIP LOCKED

-- insert data to tableB 
INSERT tableB VALUES SELECT values from tableA
    
-- update data 
UPDATE tableA SET is_proccesed = 1 where id = (from any id i have select)
```

Then trigger job process B:

```
ProcessB::dispatch(from any id i have select as string)->onQueue('queueA');
```

I have Job Process B which will be triggered by Job Process A or cron which works every minute.

```
--first select data with lock
   
SELECT *
FROM tableB
WHERE is_proccesed = 0 AND id in (parameter get from job A if any)
LIMIT 1000
FOR UPDATE OF tableB SKIP LOCKED
    
-- call API with parameter value is from tableB
-- update data
```

If (call API is success) then:

```
UPDATE tableB SET is_proccesed = 1 where id = (from any id i have select)
```

if (call API is fail) then:

```
UPDATE tableB SET is_proccesed = 0 where id = (from any id i have select)
```

- I have a cron running every minute that will call/dispatch Job Process A if any is_processed flag is 0 in table A.
- I have a cron running every minute which call/dispatch Job Process B if there is_processed flag which is 0 in table B.
- I use supervisor to do this in real time and use max-retry for jobs that fail 3 times.

My problem is:

- I have double process call API from job process B,
- I have scrolled through my logs and the SELECT key got 2 data from 2 different processes at the same time. (in some cases with 2000 or more data to process),
- It doesn't always happen to process a bit of data.

My question is:

- Is select data with lock not working with queue jobs?
- Is it correct to create cron to notify job manually to reprocess unsuccessful data, or should I apply a failed job only to rework jobs?

Comment: This will help you: [mpyw/laravel-database-advisory-lock: Advisory Locking Features for Postgres/MySQL on Laravel](https://github.com/mpyw/laravel-database-advisory-lock)

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen many Web languages that use database locks correctly.  Without looking at the Laravel code, I would guess that it does not use database locks correctly for jobs.  I know that it does not use locks for migrate.  Running migrate from >2 web nodes is not safe.

If you use Redis or some other technology for jobs instead of SQL DB, a lot of concurrent problems will probably go away.

### Manage your own global lock

You can manage your own lock and add synchronization between your own processes.

```php
    $results = \DB::select('SELECT GET_LOCK("process-b", 120) as obtain_lock');
    if (!$results[0]->obtain_lock) { return 0; }
    //120 is seconds to wait for lock or fail

    //load one record

    //call API

    //update one record

    //free lock
    $results = \DB::select('SELECT RELEASE_LOCK("process-b")');
    if (!$results[0]->obtain_lock) { return -1; } //couldn't release lock, stop process, free mysql connection
```

In Postgresql they are called "advisory locks", but you cannot use characters, you have to use numbers

```php
    $results = \DB::select('SELECT pg_advisory_lock(1337)');
    if (!$results) { return 0; }  // ???

    //load one record

    //call API

    //update one record

    //free lock
    $results = \DB::select('SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(1337)');
    if (!$results) { return -1; } //??? how to check for success?
```

### Use "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE"

I'm not sure if you are trying to use `FOR UPDATE` locks and it is not working, or you are skipping the lock with intention.

You need to turn off autocommit (`set autocommit=0`) to use lock FOR UPDATE or to start a transaction.

```php
\DB::transaction( function () use ($id) {
    $results = \DB::table('table_b')->select('SELECT * from table_b where ID=?', $id)->lockForUpdate()->get();
    \DB::table('table_b')->update('UPDATE table_b set x=y where ID=?', $id);
});
```

Where ProcA sends jobs to ProcB, you can make 1 ProcB job for each ID that is processed=0 - OR -  you can make 1 ProcB job whenever you find any processed=0 records.

So, if ProcB will only work with 1 record ID, then global lock solution is probably not good.

You can check that your lock for update is working by putting `sleep()` and creating 10-20 ProcB jobs with the same record ID.  If you sleep for 3 seconds, and it takes 30-60 seconds to finish all ProcB jobs, then the lock for update is working properly.  If they all finish in 3 seconds, then they are not respecting the lock on the record.

### Bonus

Add this to your `routes/console.php` to get concurrent-safe `artisan lockingmigrate` command

```php
$signature = 'lockingmigrate {--database= : The database connection to use}
                {--force : Force the operation to run when in production}
                {--path=* : The path(s) to the migrations files to be executed}
                {--realpath : Indicate any provided migration file paths are pre-resolved absolute paths}
                {--pretend : Dump the SQL queries that would be run}
                {--seed : Indicates if the seed task should be re-run}
                {--step : Force the migrations to be run so they can be rolled back individually}';

Artisan::command($signature, function ($database=false, $seed=false, $step=false, $pretend=false, $force=false) {
    $results = \DB::select('SELECT GET_LOCK("artisan-migrate", 120) as migrate');
    if (!$results[0]->migrate) { return -1; }
    $params = [
        '--pretend' => $pretend,
        '--force'   => $force,
        '--step'    => $step,
        '--seed'    => $seed,
    ];
    $retval = Artisan::call('migrate', $params);
    $outputLines = explode("\n", trim(\Artisan::output()));
    dump($outputLines);
    \DB::select('SELECT RELEASE_LOCK("artisan-migrate")');
    return $retval;
})->describe('Concurrent-safe migrate');
```

Comment: I think his question not just about cron but i think he want combine queue jobs with cron.

Actually, i have tested 2 cron job only with "FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED" and everything working fine. Does not know queue jobs running together with cron job.

Comment: Thanks for reply, 

yes, that's right, I had a problem when combining cron with queue job laravel, from my experiments there were two different job / worker processes such as using the same db transaction. I know this after printing random numbers on the laravel log (8 digit random numbers) to mark 2 processes the same or different. As a result I have 2 work processes that get the same data selection from the database.

Comment: I have also tried locking tables using the sleep function (10 seconds) and 2 cron processes, and have received the same issue (data double). is it correct to use for update skip locked or it is safer to use for update lock only.? Thanks,